# Using a variable created within a class method in another class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Using OOP based tkinter, I wish to use a variable created within a class method in another class, i.e. not the one in which it was created.

The variable that I wish to use is 'MainGameWindow', the identifier for the instance of the class I am dealing with. It is initially created inside the class 'LoginWindow' in the method 'LoginUser', shown below:

```
def LoginUser(self):
    self.username=self.entry_username.get()
    self.usertg=self.entry_tutorg.get()
    self.logdetails=str(self.username)+' '+str(self.usertg)+'.txt'
    if os.path.isfile(self.logdetails)==True:
        #opening of main window
        self.master.destroy()
        root=Tk()
        MainGameWindow=MainGameClass(root)
```

I wish to then use this variable in another class, 'OptionsClass', in order to execute a class method in the 'MainGameClass' (the 'MainGameWindow' instance) using a command:

```
  self.radio_targetapp1=Radiobutton(self.master,text="Standard Mole",variable=self.app_var,value="placeholder1.gif",command=lambda:MainGameWindow.changeApp("placeholder1.gif"))
```

This is the method which I am attempting to execute:

```
    def changeApp(self,changeto):
       self.target_photo=PhotoImage(file=changeto)
       self.coords=self.canvas.coords(self.mole_target)
       self.theimg=self.canvas.create_image(self.coords[0],self.coords[1],image=self.target_photo)
```

In its current state I get the error 'NameError: global name 'MainGameWindow' is not defined'. I assume this is because the variable was created inside a class function and is therefore a local variable - how do I therefore use this variable outside of this function?

Apologies if this question is long-winded, however I have searched for an answer and have not been able to find one.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use `self.main_game_window = MainGameClass(root)`? An instance of `LoginUser` would then have the `main_game_window` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not `return MainGameWindow` from `LoginUser` and store it where you want?

If you don't want to do that, an alternative (not recommended) is

```
global MainGameWindow
MainGameWindow = MainGameClass(root)
```

This puts `MainGameWindow` in the global namespace.

Unrelated, `if os.path.isfile(self.logdetails) == True:` should simply be `if os.path.isfile(self.logdetails):`.